# How can I canvas an icon in web pages using chrome extension?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension, font-awesome, ico

I built a Chrome extension, to highlight phone numbers on web pages. Besides highlighting the numbers I want to append an icon at the end of each number. Here I have two options:

1. Using font awesome icons.
2. Using `.ico` file.

There is a problem with font awesome icons. When I tried font awesome unicodes they are rendering as blank squares and with fa-phone class, nothing had rendered, may be because of the particular site may not support font awesome icons. I don't know how to solve the issue.

If font awesome is not a good idea, then I want to know, How can I append `.ico` file in `<span>`.

Comment: Did you remember to attach the CSS file (Style Sheet), which is probably why your getting the error.

Comment: for font awesome?

Comment: yes, You need to download the CSS file and attach that somehow to the page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about making extensions but web pages are basically built from HTML and CSS.

FontAwesome should first be linked with the page and then add the HTML code to show the icon.

Icons is probably not showing because you have the HTML code but didn't link the CSS to the page. So somehow, you need to link the CSS file with the page.

You could add the link to CSS file like so (Requires hosting the CSS file):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

or attach the file in the extension, so it doesn't have to be fetched from a site (recommended method).

Comment: I don't know how this would be done in Chrome Extension but it should be possible because there are other extensions which are able to do this.

Comment: I don't think that it is good, to modify meta tags of other's sites.

Comment: why not store the css file in the extension and just add HTML snippets (code for icon) on the page. Would that not be possible and sufficient ?

Comment: how about icon file?

Comment: Can you tell me which icon your using ? - (I want the HTML code to explain)

Comment: I have a .ico file, I want to use that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153943/discussion-between-webguy-and-sitchie).